# Variable-rate timelapse

Tags: ffmpeg, time-lapse

I'm making a timelapse which slows down for portions of the video which contain content of interest.

I have an input video file; for each frame, I would like that frame to appear 0 or more times in the output. (I'd also like to be able to take several frames in a row and average them together to make one frame, but if that is not feasible I would consider just skipping frames instead.) For example, perhaps I want frame 1 to not appear in the output, frame 2 to appear four times, and frames 3 through 5 to be averaged into a single frame. (I've already completed a separate pre-processing step that determines what I want for each frame.) The typical input file is about 40k frames.

What is an efficient way to accomplish this goal? Currently I am using the imageio python library, but that introduces a lot of overhead, and the averaging together of frames is by itself taking more than half of the computation time. (I can cut that a little by being more careful with memory allocation, but I expect that to be a marginal improvement.)

I'm unfamiliar with what alternatives to imageio suitable for this task there are. Perhaps this can be accomplished with ffmpeg directly? The "setpts" and "minterpolate" filters seem relevant but I don't understand how/if they can be used for my purpose. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/How%20to%20speed%20up%20/%20slow%20down%20a%20video

Thanks.